# "Single Line statements lambdas must include exactly one statement." Why this error?

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I am using VB.Net to assign a Delegate. But in that I do not want to define a Method(Sub)/Function.

Simply giving `Nothing` do not work because `DelegateCommand` throws runtime exception if `Nothing` is set in Delegate.

So why am I getting this error?

`"Single Line statements lambdas must include exactly one statement."`

Here is the code

```
Public Delegate Function DelegateCommand(Of T)(ByVal arg As T) As Boolean

Private _foobar As DelegateCommand(Of Object)
Public ReadOnly Property FooBar() As DelegateCommand(Of Object)
    Get
        If _foobar Is Nothing Then
            _foobar = New DelegateCommand(Of Object)(Sub(), AddressOf OnFooBarCommandExecuted)
        End If
        Return _foobar
    End Get
End Property

Private Function OnFooBarCommandExecuted(ByVal parameter As Object) As Boolean
    Return False
End Function
```

Here is the Image

[image]

Comment: Can't you create a non-sensitive copy of the code, and show us it *as text*? Or better yet,  create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036549/vb-net-statement-lambdas-cannot-be-converted-to-expression-trees-compile-tim

Comment: @JoachimPileborg:Done.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal can you post the code as text instead? if I wan't to fix this I do need to rewrite everything by myself instead of copy and paste

Comment: for `sub` routines ,a `statement` is required. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff759254.aspx

Comment: So you want a [`DelegateCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410(v=pandp.40).aspx) whose `Execute(T)` does nothing and `CanExecute(T)` calls `OnFooBarCommandExecuted`? (If yes, Sarvesh's deleted answer is correct)

Comment: @Amit undeleted the answer, it may not be the perfect answer but it resolves the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VB.NET compiler team had a fair amount of trouble shoe-horning support for lambda expressions into the language.  Definitely not easy to do in an old, *old* language like Basic.  You give it a very hard time generating the "best" diagnostic, the language parser falls over first on having to match a Sub() with no arguments with a Function() with an argument.  Can't do that, it won't know what to pass as the function argument value.  And worse, it needs to generate MSIL code to cleanup the stack and pop the function return value but your Sub() says there is no code.  The discrepancy makes it yell Eeek! with a lousy diagnostic and give up.

Before it can discover that there's something more fundamentally wrong with the code, it tries to pass two methods to the delegate constructor.  The bigger problem you should know about, unfortunately not reported because it gave up on the first error.

The Roslyn project is notable, the language parser was completely rewritten and it generates a better diagnostic for this code.  Integrated into VS2015, you now get:

> error BC32008: Delegate 'ConsoleApplication1.Example.DelegateCommand(Of Object)' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor.

That gets you somewhere, note *as the only argument* in the error message.  Two ways to do that as hinted in the error message.  A valid 'AddressOf` expression as the only argument:

```
    _foobar = New DelegateCommand(Of Object)(AddressOf OnFooBarCommandExecuted)
```

Or a lambda expression as the only argument:

```
    _foobar = New DelegateCommand(Of Object)(Function(parameter)
                                                 Return False
                                             End Function)
```

With no longer a need to write the OnFooBarCommandExecuted() function, what you wanted to accomplish.  VB.NET provides plenty of syntax sugar to simplify this code further.  You can declare the lambda expression to take no argument, even though the delegate declared one.  And you don't have to write the delegate construction code explicitly, the compiler can infer it from the `_foobar` variable.  Which collapses the code to:

```
    _foobar = Function() False
```

Comment: OP didn't answer my comment/question, but since you obviously found a widely accepted answer... don't you think OP intention is to return a value from `FooBar` such that calling `CanExecute` would return `False`, and calling `Execute` would have no effect? And if the answer is yes, how does your answer address that?

Comment: (BTW, I'm pretty certain your edit to the question itself led you to this answer, and that it is wrong. You defined a new Delegate instead of using [DelegateCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410(v=pandp.40).aspx) that OP intended - see comment on Sarvesh's answer)

Comment: I did not define a new delegate, the declaration was missing from the question.  So I provided one.  The OP can correct it if necessary, I doubt it is necessary.

Comment: Did you notice the type I linked to? did you read OP's comment? do you *really* think your edit matches that comment? what "two constructors" are there in your edit? (I'm really trying hard to understand this :-)

Comment: I don't see any hint whatsoever that this has something to do with Prism.  The OP needs to edit his question to keep you happy, I recommend you talk to him instead of me.

Comment: No problem :-) please don't take it hard, I was trying to figure out what you saw there that I didn't. Anyway seems like OP is actually happy with this answer (again, by his recent comments).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change some of the codes
In the getter of Property, use this line of code

```
_foobar = New DelegateCommand(Of Object)(Sub()
                                         End Sub, AddressOf OnFooBarCommandExecuted)
```

A single line lambda must have only 1 statement, so `Sub()` being a single line lambda it expects a statement. If your Method has no statement then you cannot use single line lambda.

A zero statement lambda is

```
Dim zeroStatementLambda = Sub()
                          End Sub
```

And it seem to be case where you can use the single parameter for DelegateCommand constructor

```
_foobar = New DelegateCommand(Of Object)(AddressOf OnFooBarCommandExecuted)
```

Change the definition of OnFooBarCommandExecuted

```
Private Function OnFooBarCommandExecuted() As Func(Of Object, Boolean)
    Return Function(parameter As Object, Boolean)
               Return False
           End Function
End Function
```

Comment: DelegateCommand class has two constructor. You are refering to the one which takes one parameter. My question is about the one which takes two parameters.

Comment: @amit: I know the solution and how to rectify this but wanted to know behind the scene which I guess Hans Passant suits.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal then respectfully you found a super-complicated way to ask your question, and I don't understand what any of the details (Including use of `DelegateCommand`, the property and so on) have to do with this. But hey, at least you got your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Sub() before AddressOf, if you want to pass only one delegate to DelagateCommand constructor, like this

```
Public ReadOnly Property FooBar() As DelegateCommand(Of Object)
    Get
        If _foobar Is Nothing Then
            _foobar = New DelegateCommand(Of Object)(AddressOf OnFooBarCommandExecuted)
        End If
        Return _foobar
    End Get
End Property
```

You can assign a delegate either anonymously with Sub() ... statements, or with the AddressOf operator where you pass the name of the existing function, not both.

But I think you are actually trying to pass two delegates to your DelegateCommand. First the command to execute and the second is Func returning if the command can be executed.
In that case you need to add some statements to the first parameter.
Like this,

```
Public ReadOnly Property FooBar() As DelegateCommand(Of Object)
    Get
        If _foobar Is Nothing Then
            _foobar = New DelegateCommand(Of Object)(Sub() 
                                                     'statement here
                                                     End Sub, AddressOf OnFooBarCommandExecuted)
        End If
        Return _foobar
    End Get
End Property
```